# Consulta inner join para mostrar el nombre con la id en dos tablas PHP

Tags: php, sql, join

Tengo dos tablas, una llamada `articulos`, y otra llamada `categorias`. En la tabla `articulos` una columna llamada `id_categoria` guarda el *ID* de las categorías disponibles en la tabla `categorias`, y deseo mostrar mediante el *ID* de categoría el nombre de esta misma, tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<?php
$id_categoria=$row['id_categoria'];
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from categorias where id_categoria='$id_categoria'");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['nombre_categoria'];?></td>  
<?php
}
?>
```

Tablas:

```
TABLA-ARTICULOS
id_producto      nombre_producto      id_categoria
===================================================
1                Prueba                     2


TABLA-CATEGORIAS
id_categoria      nombre_categoria
==================================
1                Prueba1       
2                Prueba2
```

Listo logre solucionarlo, me faltaba el $id_categoria=$row['id_categoria']; para poder usar los datos Gracias a todos. edite el codigo arriba para que vean como lo solucione.

Comment: es decir quieres una consulta que te devuelva un resultado como la segunda tabla?

Comment: Exacto, este pequeño codigo lo tengo en un archivo llamado articulo.php donde me muestra la informacion del articulo seleccionado, ejemplo, al seleccionar el articulo 1, me mostrara como un perfil, en tal perfil me muestra todos los datos alojados, y desearia que en la id_categoria me mostrara el nombre de esa categoria en la segunda tabla.

Comment: Haz `echo $row['nombre_categoria'];` y listo.

Comment: Me sale un error al poner echo $row['nombre_categoria']; , me sale: notice: Undefined index: nombre_categoria in articulo.php on line 140 ( la linea 140 es la del echo)

Comment: yo le agregaria un alias a cada columna y cuando le realices el fetch_assoc podes hacer el `echo $row['alias utilizado en el query'];` o fijate que te devuelve el `echo $row['categorias'];`

Comment: Me arroja el siguiente error ` Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in articulo.php on line 143` ( la linea del while )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugas los nombres de las tablas no tienen que ser iguales, eso va a generar conflicto. Lo idea es tener algo asi:

```
TABLA: articulos
id      nombre                   idCategoria
================================================
1       Soldador de Estaño       1
2       PC                       2
3       Teclado                  2

TABLA: categoria
idCate      nombreCate
================================================
1           Electronica       
2           Computacion

<?php
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=BASEDEDATOS', 'ROOT', 'PASS');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$code = $_GET['id']; //teniendo en cuenta que viene desde un link `.php?id=3`

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM articulos INNER JOIN categoria ON categoria.idCate = articulos.cateId WHERE articulos.id = '".$code."'");
$row = $sql->fetch();
?>
ID de articulo: <?=$row['id'];?>
<p style="font-family: Arial; margin: 0 0 10px;">
Producto: <?=$row['nombre'];?><br>
en categoria <?=$row['nombreCate'];?>
</p>
```

Lo que hice fue también cambiar en la tabla `articulos` el nombre de los mismo por `artNombre` para no generar problemas.
Espero haberte ayudado, solo recordá no crear tablas con mismos nombres cuando uses `inner join`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me funciona pero.. en vez de solo arrojarme 1 solo resultado, me arroja 3, ( tengo 3 articulos ingresados, si agrego otro, saldrian 4 ) Sale así    
    Categoría: Producto sshhshs
en categoria Mesones

Producto Probando
en categoria Artículos de Oficina

Producto Ordenadores
en categoria Equipos Informáticos

Comment: Resultado: http://i67.tinypic.com/9rul5f.jpg

Comment: Deberia arrojar los tres... ahi me fijo que puede estar mal

Comment: Ahi deberia funcionar... agregue mas artículos y me fije que este llamando bien a las dos tablas

Comment: Pero, lo que necesito es que me arroje solo un resultado, no todos, osea, el codigo lo tengo colocado en un perfil (ejemplo) articulo.php?id=2 donde solo me arroja toda la informacion de 1 solo articulo en este caso el ID 2, y dentro de el solo necesito mostrar el nmbre de la categoria de ESE ID 2 , si me doy a entender?

Comment: aaah.... dame un minuto

Comment: Listo, ahi hice unos cambios, primero la tabla, `categoria`, cambien el `idCate` para que no genere conflictos al pedir el `id` y teniendo en cuenta que viene desde `articulo.php?id=2`, bueno yo puse `3`, te va a traer el producto que solicitas y no una lista.

Answer (score 2):

Por las llaves que pusiste parece que falta algo de código ahí, deberías repasar la pregunta.

Si lo que muestas es tal cual lo tienes, el problema está en el `SELECT p.id_articulo...` que debería ser `SELECT p.id_producto...`

Yo soy muy quisquilloso con los nombres usados y creo que es una buena practica usar un serie de patrones, que además de agilizar el análisis y la programación, facilitan el intercambio de código y la programación en grupo.

Algunas reglas básicas serían:

> Los nombres de tablas **siempre** en plural. Por ejemplo: `categorias`
>
> El campo `Primary Key` **siempre** existe, **siempre** es un autoincremental y **siempre** se llama `id`
>
> Las `Foreing Keys` **siempre** se llaman `id` + `_` + `nombre_de_tabla_en_singular`: Por ejemplo: `id_categoria`
>
> **Nunca** se repite el nombre de la tabla en un campo, por ejemplo: `nombre_articulo` en la tabla `articulos`. Es información redundante,
>   pues con solo poner `nombre` ya sugiere que se trata del nombre del
>   artículo (la tabla o el alias lo indicará). Si estuviera
>   justificado usar el nombre de la tabla para "facilitar" la comprensión
>   también se debería usar en el resto de campos: `color_articulo`,
>   `familia_articulo`, `precio_articulo`.... y eso no se suele hacer.
>   También permite poder usar métodos o propiedades genéricos que funcionarán en la mayoría de las ocasiones, por ejemplo:  `$registro->nombre` sabemos que nos funcionará en la mayoría de de las consultas, ya se trate de la tabla `articulos`, `categorias` o `clientes`, con lo cual obtenemos un código más reusable.
>
> Usar nombres de tablas/campos semánticamente coherentes con su
>   funcionalidad, usando palabras completas y separadas por guión bajo en caso
>   de palabras múltiples, por ejemplo, la tabla `permRespAlm` sería `permisos_responsable_almacen` con lo cual se genera un código más legible y por tanto más fácil de mantener, aunque sea  más largo.

De esta forma tus tablas quedarían:

```
TABLA: articulos
id      nombre      id_categoria
===================================================
1       Prueba       2


TABLA: categorias
id      nombre
==================================
1       Prueba1       
2       Prueba2
```

Y la consulta llamada de forma correcta (tal como te indica @ivan.depi) iterando sobre el resultado:

```
<?php
$id_del_articulo = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = ' SELECT a.id, a.id_categoria, a.nombre, c.nombre as categoria
           FROM articulos AS a
          INNER JOIN categorias AS c ON c.id = a.id_categoria
          WHERE a.id = '.$id_del_articulo;

$query = $con->query($sql);
while ($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
    echo " Artículo: $row->nombre  Categoría: $row->categoria <br>".PHP_EOL ;    
}

?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciona pero, me da el mismo detalle que Stn, me salen 3 resultados, Categoría: Equipos Informáticos 
Categoría: Artículos de Oficina 
Categoría: Mesones         ( tengo 3 articulos ingresados, si agrego otro, saldrian 4 )

Comment: Resultado:  http://i66.tinypic.com/2wfn0cz.jpg

Comment: Lo que te falta es filtrar por `id`de artículo, por lo que comentas te salen todos los registros ¿no?

Comment: Al parecer si amigo, me salen todos los articulos que estan asociados con las categorias, edite el echo asi "echo "Categoría: $row->categorias <br>".PHP_EOL ; " para q solo me arroje el nombre de la categoria pero me salen todos. Como haria ahora para q solo me salga el asociado a ese articulo. ?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y pon el código actual, porque tus comentarios no concuerdan con el código expuesto, no deberia salirte todas las categorias si estas filtrando por un solo artículo.

Comment: Listo ya la edite, otra cosa, al usar el WHERE que añadiste, me arroja este error:  error: syntax error, unexpected 'a' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sicpad\articulo.php on line 138

Answer (score 1):

La variable query, recoge todas las filas devueltas. Debes recorrer el objeto primero.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id_articulo, p.id_categoria, c.id_categoria, c.nombre_categoria as 
categorias
FROM articulos p
INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.id_categoria = c.id_categoria";
$query = $con->query($sql);


while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['id_categoria'];
    echo "\n";
    echo $row['categorias'];
}
```

Comment: Me arroja el siguiente error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in articulo.php on line 143` ( la linea del while )

Answer (score 1):

¿Has probado la consulta directamente en la base de datos para asegurarte que funciona y que esta todo correcto? Comprueba también los espacios dentro de la consulta a mí me paso una vez que me dio error porque la puse en varias líneas dentro del php tal como la tienes tú. También lo del "assoc" alguna vez no me fue bien del todo, sustituye por "fetch_array".

Prueba así a ver.

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT p.id_articulo, c.id_categoria, c.nombre_categoria as categorias FROM articulos p INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.id_categoria = c.id_categoria";
$query = $con->query($sql);

$total_rows = $query->num_rows;

if($total_rows > 0){
   while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
       echo $row['id_categoria'];
       echo "\n";
       echo $row['categorias'];
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: No me funciona así amigo :(  Sale: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in line 137